# WordPress prévia do post sem o link "read more"

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Olá,

Sou iniciante na plataforma Wordpress, e me encontro em uma situação onde não quero que apareça o link "Continue lendo" nas prévias de meus posts.

Para adicionar as prévias dos posts na home, usei o seguinte código:

```
<article class="article-noticia-home">
<?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
    <div class="noticias-home-image-container">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id()); ?>" />
        </a>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
<header>
    <h3 class="recent-blog-entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
</header>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

Até ai beleza, mas onde coloco o "`<?php the_excerpt(); ?>`"  ele traz uma parte do meu post e um link de Leia mais.

```
<article class="article-noticia-home">
<div class="noticias-home-image-container">
    <a href="http://cristalink.com.br/site/2016/05/04/titulo-noticia-04/" title="Título Notícia 04">
        <img src="http://cristalink.com.br/site/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/noticia04.jpg">
    </a>
</div>
<header>
    <h3 class="recent-blog-entry-title"><a href="http://cristalink.com.br/site/2016/05/04/titulo-noticia-04/" title="Título Notícia 04">Título Notícia 04</a></h3>
</header>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vestibulum justo ut quam posuere,
ullamcorper ultrices est sagittis. Morbi rhoncus, erat nec convallis pharetra, tellus urna pharetra tellus,
ut lacinia arcu enim vitae enim. Aenean faucibus, erat vel posuere commodo, purus purus dignissim nibh, 
in laoreet lectus Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. … 
    <a href="http://cristalink.com.br/site/2016/05/04/titulo-noticia-04/" class="more-link">
        Continue lendo 
        <span class="screen-reader-text">Título Notícia 04</span> 
        <span class="meta-nav">→</span>
    </a>
</p>
```

Como faço para continuar com somente prévia do post, e sem o link?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adiciona esse pedaço de código na sua `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'bacon_more' );
    function bacon_more() {
        return '';
    }
```

Ele adiciona um filtro pra retornar nada no lugar do read more

Comment: Cara eu entendi o funcionamento, mas não ta funcionando, pode ter alteração na chamada 'the_content_more_link' dependendo do tema que estou usando?

Comment: Consegui achar aqui :) o tema q eu utilizo usava outro add_filter usando o the_content() pra forçar a colocar o link.
alterei a function q ja existia com o q você falou acima, com o return '' na variável que ele mesmo criava para adicionar a prévia do post e o link.
funcionou certinho, muito obrigado :D